# scrape a table with rvest in R that has mismatch table heading

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape this table which seems like it would be super simple. 
Here's the url of the table: https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?position=1&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek=1

Here's what I coded:

```
url <- "https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?position=1&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek=1"
x = data.frame(read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table())
```

This works ok but gives really weird two row headers and when I try to add %>% slice(-1) to take out the top row it says I can't because it's a list. Would really like to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Right now, the output is a list. You want to convert it to a data frame. `html_table() %>% as.data.frame` converts the list to a data frame. Then, you can use slice(), if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution. An explanation follows.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>%  
  html_table(header = T) %>%
  simplify() %>% 
  first() %>% 
  setNames(paste0(colnames(.), as.character(.[1,]))) %>%
  slice(-1)
```

Output of `glimpse()`:

```
Observations: 25
Variables: 16
$ Rank          <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"…
$ Player        <chr> "Lamar Jackson QB - BAL", "Dak Prescott QB - DAL", "Deshaun W…
$ Opp           <chr> "@MIA", "NYG", "@NO", "@ARI", "@JAX", "@PHI", "PIT", "WAS", "…
$ PassingYds    <chr> "324", "405", "268", "385", "378", "380", "341", "313", "248"…
$ PassingTD     <chr> "5", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "…
$ PassingInt    <chr> "-", "-", "1", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "1", "1", "1", "…
$ RushingYds    <chr> "6", "12", "40", "22", "2", "-", "-", "5", "24", "6", "13", "…
$ RushingTD     <chr> "-", "-", "1", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "…
$ ReceivingRec  <chr> "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "…
$ ReceivingYds  <chr> "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "…
$ ReceivingTD   <chr> "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "…
$ RetTD         <chr> "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "…
$ MiscFumTD     <chr> "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "…
$ Misc2PT       <chr> "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "1", "-", "…
$ FumLost       <chr> "-", "-", "-", "1", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "…
$ FantasyPoints <chr> "33.56", "33.40", "30.72", "27.60", "27.32", "27.20", "25.64"…
```

**Explanation**
From `?html_table` docs:

> `html_table` currently makes a few assumptions:
>
> - No cells span multiple rows
> - Headers are in the first row

Part of your problem is solved by setting `header = TRUE` in `html_table()`.

Another part of the problem is that the header cells span two rows, which `html_table()` does not expect.

Assuming you don't want to lose the information in either header row, you can:

1. Use `simplify` and `first` to pull out the data frame from the list you get from `html_table`
2. Use `setNames` to merge the two header rows (which are now the data frame columns and the first row)
3. Remove the first row (now redundant) with `slice`