# Can't Scrape with Rvest and Glue packages bc Table has merged header cols making it untidy

Tags: r, tidyr, rvest

I am trying to run a scrape with Rvest and Glue packages to loop over 17 weeks of football data by four positions. But I'm having trouble with col headings on the scrape. Here is the page I'm trying to scrape from:

https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?position=1&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek=1

The issue I'm having is that the table header has a few merged cells making it quite untidy. And I need to make a function that uses the Glue package to scrape this table as it applies to each of the 17 weeks of data for four positions (QB,RB,WR,TE).

Here is what I've tried so far as a function to scrape in this manner:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(rvest) 
library(glue) 

url <- "https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?position=1&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek=1"

scrape_19 <- function(week, position) {

Sys.sleep(3)  

cat(".")

    url <- glue::glue("https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?position={position}&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek={week}")
read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  purrr::flatten_df() %>%
  setNames(paste0(colnames(.), as.character(.[1,]))) %>%
  slice(-1) 
}

#test shows it all go awry
scrape_19(6, 1)
```

I can tell what's going on here. The call above (I believe the flatten function) is merging the two col heading together but for first row col heading like "Passing" there are three second row col headings below it and the call is only taking the last of these three in consideration. Same goes with the other row 1 headings.

Anyway, I'm open to any other way of tidying the col headings so I can proceed with the scrape.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235341/scrape-a-table-with-rvest-in-r-that-has-mismatch-table-heading

Comment: @akrun: That's the desired solution

Comment: so that was my link from yesterday but it didn't quite work as I thought. The first row header issue that I mentioned in this post was the result of that call